# IIS Application Pools: Listing Configuration

Tags: iis-8

I am attempting to list certain sections of an app pool in IIS. I already have the script to set the attribute but haven't been able to find the one to list it. For example, to set the Rapid-Fail Protection to "true", I use:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools "/[name='$appPool'].failure.rapidFailProtection:true"  /commit:apphost
```

where $appPool is the name of your app. This method works fine. However, if I change it to something like:

```
appcmd list config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools "/[name='$appPool'].failure.rapidFailProtection"
```

It fails with 
ERROR ( message:The attribute "[name='$appPool'].failure.rapidFailProtection" is not supported in the current command usage. )

I also tried a few variations such as the following but they had the same error:

```
appcmd list apppool $appPool /section:failure.rapidFailProtection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer to my own question just via a different avenue. I was able to view the values using the following syntax:

> $appPool = "AppPool1"
>
> (Get-Item "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool").failure.rapidFailProtection

Using the $appPool variable I can create a loop to pull the values for each app pool.